# Unable to locate file "xxx" in this project or a referenced project IIB

Tags: eclipse, ibm-integration-bus

Unable to locate file "TestSubFlow.subflow" in this project or a referenced project.

[image]

My project hierarchy.

IIB Version: 10.0.0.5

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your project's hierarchy? Are the flow and the subflow in the same schema? Which version of IIB are you using?

Comment: IIB Version: 10.0.0.5
No, different packages

Comment: In the screenshot below, your Subflow is in the defaut Broker package, and in the error message it is in gen/X.subflow. I guess you the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with a referenced library.
Solved by deleting the library from the workspace and reimporting it.